# Why weren't there any aliens in Time?

Tags: stephen-baxter, manifold-time, fermi-paradox

I recently finished listening to an audio book version of [Stephen Baxter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Baxter)'s [Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold:_Time).  I listened to almost the entire story but I missed a few short segments due to various distractions and it was difficult to rewind.

Anyway, a central theme of the [Manifold trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold_Trilogy) is the [Fermi Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_paradox) and different possible solutions.   In this novel, humanity and its descendants could not find life anywhere else in the universe, nor in any other alternate universes that they had explored, they were always empty.

> Until the collapse of the false vacuum of our universe, at the end of the novel.

Why was the universe/multiverse totally empty?
It seems like there would, at least, be another human-like race in our universe?

If it was the [false vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum), why would that cause aliens to be nonexistent?

Comment: What's the downvote for?  Seems like a fair question.

Comment: IIRC, the whole point of the book is exploring this very question.  Your question is a bit like asking "I recently finished LOTR. Why did Frodo need to destroy the ring?" That might explain the downvote. // Still, its a decent question, I am voting you up.  I can't answer because its been too long since I read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the ["Fermi Paradox"](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/fermi_paradox),  at *Sci-Fi Encyclopedia*:

> The Drake equation is flawed or has been misinterpreted or fed with
>   incorrect values. We are indeed unique and alone, as in Stephen
>   Baxter's Time: Manifold 1

This point is actually more implied rather than outright stated in the novel, which is probably why people are having a hard time remembering why there were no aliens.

**Its not that we haven't found any aliens that are out there somewhere, its just that life is very unlikely in our universe and thus only we came into existence.**  This explains part of the downstreamer desire to collapse the false vacuum, and thus allow more species to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Although as zipquincy states "the whole point of the book is exploring the question" the real answer is space--it is hard to investigate a huge area (covering a universe takes immense time), time--not all species will have the same development cycle in time as humanity, aliens and security--they might not feel it in their interests to be found, and the problem of looking for a needle in the haystack. Also, the requirements for the initiation of life involve a set of requirements in the host planets that include water, temperature, pressure, atmosphere, and chemistry.

Some of the readily available nontechnical resources that discuss the problems of the universe are found [in one my blog posts that review them](http://www.embracingliterature.com/nonfict/big-bang-books-the-breakdown) if you would like more information.

Comment: In the series humanity had explored much of the universe with no luck finding aliens.  I don't remember any talk in the book about not finding the aliens because of the shear area to cover.   Also, the focus of this particular novel was more on humanity and life attempting to survive the heat death of the universe rather than focusing on the Fermi Paradox.  While I agree it was a point of the series, I don't think it was a central point of this particular novel, unless I missed some key line, which I'm trying to discover.